# openconnect vpn not change resolv.conf from GUI . Fedora 29

Tags: linux, fedora, vpn, cisco, openconnect

I try to connect to the VPN with openvpn.
If I connect from the cli with sudo openconnect..... its working fine. The vpn change the /etc/resolv.conf to the desired format.

But If I would connect from the GUI. Settings > Network > VPN it doesn-t change the resolv.conf

The SELinux is in permissive mode

Answer (score -2, accepted):

/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Should contains the following setting

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

And everything will goes well. If you want to keep an ability to use internet during you are on vpn. Add the google dns (8.8.8.8) to the vpn settings aswel